# Spring Webflux throws different exception when called from Web and WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webtestclient

I have a controller which has a GET mapping with a couple of request params and a request header. Something like this

```
@GetMapping
public Mono<Response> getAll(@RequestParam("someId") String someId,
                             @RequestParam("someOtherId") String someOtherId,
                             @RequestHeader(SOME_TOKEN) String someToken) { }
```

I have a controller advice where I am catching exceptions and sending customized messages and http codes back.
I noticed that when I call from web(or via some rest client), if any of the request params or header is missing, following exceptions are thrown,

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException
```

In my unit tests I am using

```
@WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class)
```

and

```
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webClient;
```

When I try calling the endpoint without required param or header, I get the folowwing exception

```
org.springframework.web.server.MissingRequestValueException
```

Because of this my `@ExceptionHandlers` in Controller advices are not triggered.
Is this a mistake or am I missing something here.

Shouldn't spring throw the same exception irrespective of where the call is coming from? If that is not the case, we cannot really test controller advices.

Comment: You are probably sending some Request Type when you are using a REST Client or from the Browser, however you need to be very meticulous when you are doing the rest on the TEST side, it needs to match what you are doing on the REST Client to receive the same errors.

You are missing something, and that is why you are hitting this org.springframework.web.server.MissingRequestValueException error first.  

Its because it has not had a chance to reach the other possible errors you have in your advise controller.

Comment: Actually, Flux is throwing that error: org.springframework.web.server.MissingRequestValueException

Comment: Can you provide some codebase sample to reproduce and test some scenarios if possible?

Comment: `@webFluxTest` might create a restricted application context, without the controller advice. Does the problem persist when replacing `@webFluxTest` with `@SpringBootTest` ? If it does, and you still want to use webfluxTest, then maybe you have to find a way to embed the controller advice in the test